# Different height in ListView

Tags: listview, height

I would like to have different height in different rows in a a ListView. Especially I would like to hide rows (height = 0) and then show them again. I have tried setHeight and setMinimumHeight, but I can't get it working. I would be greatful if anybody could help me.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.t = textView;
    holder.i = imageView;
    rowView.setTag(holder);

    ViewHolder tag = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    tag.t.setText(values.get(position).getName() + " ");

    if (values.get(position).isSelected()) {
        tag.i.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation);

    } 

    rowView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide/show shows at runtime, try using the `ExpandableListView` widget. Here is a nice tutorial about it: [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply! I will try using ExpandableListView. But for now I solved it by myself using the following code:

```
        rowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rowView.setMinimumHeight(0);
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```